# Translation-golf of the greatest and most famous spoiler in movie history

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Let's try another edition of the [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) tournament. This time I would like to propose a different approach to try to avoid the excessive abstraction of the sentences. So how about translating a dialogue?

The following dialogue is (arguably) the greatest and most famous spoiler in movie history. But fear not, I am quite sure you all have watched ***Star Wars Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back*** enough times to know the next quotes by heart:

> —I'll never join you!
>   —If you only knew the power of the Dark Side. Obi-Wan never told you what happened to your father.
>   —He told me enough! He told me you killed him!
>   —No. I am your father.
>   —That's not true. That's impossible!
>   —Search your feelings, you know it to be true!
>
> <sub>***202 characters***</sub>

Following is the same dialogue as we could hear it in cinemas in Spain. It is useless to hide it so:

> —Jamás me uniré a ti.
>   —Si conocieras el poder del Reverso Tenebroso. Obi-Wan no te dijo lo que le pasó a tu padre.
>   —Me dijo lo suficiente. Dijo que tú le mataste.
>   —No. Yo soy tu padre.
>   —¡Eso no es verdad! ¡Es imposible!
>   —Examina tus sentimientos, sabes que es verdad.
>
> <sub>***198 characters***</sub>

The official Spanish translation has even less characters than the original version. But, can you squeeze it even more?

This is translation-golf! **[Follow the rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637)**, explain your answers and have fun! And remember, *in just seven days, I can make you a champ!*

---

Final score:

- **aparente001**: 135 characters.
- **Diego**: 151 characters.
- **fedorqui**: 162 characters.

Very little participation this time, I must say.

Comment: Duda: _qué **le** pasó a tu padre_ podría bien ser _qué pasó a tu padre_, ¿no?

Comment: @fedorqui me suena mejor _qué pasó con tu padre_, lo malo es que así no se reduce el número de letras... Mira si puedes encontrar en el CORDE o en el CREA algún texto que use esa construcción, y si es así la usas tú también.

Comment: Caramba, es cierto que ha tenido poca participación esta vez. Parece que entrar en las HNQ ayuda y en [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/209901) explican la fórmula para aparecer allí. Lo que pesa es tener unas cuantas buenas respuestas rápidamente, así como que la pregunta tenga bastantes votos también rápidamente.

Comment: @fedorqui sí, no estoy teniendo suerte con las HNQ. Y sí, lo de la rapidez no lo había leído pero sí intuido. Parece que prima más que las respuestas sean seguidas que el que haya más o menos. También echo mucho de menos las respuestas de guifa a mis propuestas, parece que no consigo atraer su atención, con lo que habría molado la escena en castellano antiguo...

Comment: De hecho en la sección de [Hot Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) se puede ver la puntuación de cada una al momento (pasando el ratón por encima). He intentado reproducir el valor y nunca me sale el valor que dice... pero bueno, al menos sirve para ver qué cuenta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Confession: I have not seen the film.*

#### 135

> —¡Contigo, nunca!
>   —Si supieras el poder del Lado Oscuro.  Obi-Wan no te contó lo de tu papá.
>   —Lo suficiente.  Que lo mataste.
>   —No.  Soy yo tu papá.
>   —¡No!  ¡Imposible!
>   —Reflexiona, sabes que sí.

---

**Edit 2**, responding to OP's feedback:

1 - First line, still keeping in mind the context ("Join me, and I will complete your training"):

> *¡Contigo, nunca!* (12 instead of the 5 of *jamás*)

2 - Restoring the Dark Side (switching to *supieras* from *conocieras* to save space)

> Si supieras el poder del Lado Oscuro. (net gain of 4)

---

**Edit 1**:

I looked up the line of dialogue right before this excerpt begins.

> Vader: There is no escape! Don't make me destroy you. Luke, you do not yet realize your importance. You've only begun to discover your power! Join me, and I will complete your training! With our combined strength, we can end this destructive conflict, and bring order to the galaxy.

So I am modifying my first line.

> —¡Jamás!

This would brings it down to 123.

---

Response to Carlos's request for clarification:

Introduction: I recently heard an interview with Carrie Fisher, an actor who played a key role in at least the first film of the series.  Terry Gross asked her if she had ever felt bothered during her career by badly written dialogue.  Carrie gave a line from the first Star Wars film as an example of wooden dialogue.  So I started today's game from the assumption that the dialogue was wooden, tried to absorb the basic idea of each line, and go from there.  (I asked my son for the names of the characters.)

- rechazar: I think the conversation prior to "I'll never join you" must be Vader trying to recruit Luke for the Dark Side.  So I figure "I'll never join you" could be boiled down to "no way -- never."  But for the game, we don't have the benefit of the context (recruitment attempt), so "Ni madres" is not an option.  I chose "Te rechazo" as a simplified version of "I reject your club (the Dark Side) and I will never change my mind about this."
- reflexionar: I made a mistake.  When I wrote *refleja*, I meant to say *reflexiona*. If I weren't trying to conserve space, I would translate "search your feelings" as "ponte a pensar."  This is actually only one more character, so if *reflexiona* is not to people's liking, I could change this.
- Poder Oscuro: It seems to me that "el poder del Lado Oscuro" and "el Poder Oscuro" amount to the same thing.  However, as I am not steeped in Star Wars culture.  I could change this.

---

Original post:

*My translation: I felt it would be cheating to read the other answers first, so here goes:*

> —¡Te rechazo!
>   —Si conocieras el Poder Oscuro.  Obi-Wan no te contó lo de tu papá.
>   —Lo suficiente.  Que lo mataste.
>   —No.  Soy yo tu papá.
>   —¡No!  ¡Imposible!
>   —Refleja, sabes que sí.

Comment: Es un buen intento, pero no puedo aceptar esta respuesta sin que al menos expliques por qué consideras que rechazar equivale a no unirse, y el significado de refleja como equivalente a examinar los sentimientos de uno. También me gustaría que se respetara el sentido de lado oscuro y no simplemente oscuro, deberías explicar eso.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. I have fixed your character count, you have less characters in your translation than you thought (spaces and punctuation marks do not count). Nonetheless, we cannot make assumptions about what other dialogues precede or follow this one, so please try to translate the sentences making no such assumptions. I can validate your translation except the first line, try to reflect "I will never join you" better. And I would really like to keep the sense of "dark side".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - I went back to *actor* from your suggested *actress*.  In English, women actors generally prefer to be called actors now rather than actresses.  The rest is explained in the answer itself, see what you think.

Comment: I didn't know that, sorry then for my wrong correction.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Perfectly all right, and I figured you weren't aware of that, hence the explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you also for your final version, very clever approach. I can validate it now, let's see what others do!

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble following this. Maybe the "**best and final**" should be at the top of the post, with the updated character count at the very top, and then you leave the older versions under it to compare, see how your proposal evolved, etc. That way it is clearer to understand and others don't really need to read the whole thing and the comments.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - If you want *padre* instead of *papá* (and I am thinking more and more that you are right about that), my character count would only go up by two.  Let me know if I should make that change.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Do any special responsibilities come with having shaved off more letters than anyone else?  Is it up to me to propose the next round?  If so, when should that be posted?  The date you posted yours is no longer visible.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, it's in the rules. If you win you have 48 hours to think and propose a new round. After that time, anyone can propose a new round if you haven't. This game ends in 26 hours.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - How will I know if I have won?

Comment: @aparente001 I will leave a comment in the winner's answer with the notification.

Comment: You're the winner! A nice and worked out answer! As I said, you have 48 hours to propose a new game.

Comment: Well done, aparente! I am curious to see what text are you going to challenge us with :)

Comment: ¿Vas a proponer pregunta, aparente001? @CarlosAlejo ya lo comentó por allí, pero tienes un plazo de dos días, si no pasa el turno :)

Comment: De hecho, las 48 horas ya han pasado. Me pregunto si @Diego querría proponer el siguiente juego, ya que quedó segundo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Ay, no ví estos mensajes, no sé por qué.

Comment: @fedorqui - Sí, a ver cómo me sale.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>165</s> 162 caracteres

> —Nunca me uniré a ti.
>   —Si supieras el poder del Lado Oscuro. Obi-Wan nunca te contó qué pasó a tu papá.
>   —¡Me dijo harto: que tú lo mataste!
>   —No. Yo soy tu papá.
>   —¡Eso no es real! ¡Es imposible!
>   —Ojea tu sentir, lo sabes cierto.

Ya sé que suena algo aberrante lo de *Yo soy tu papá*, pues lo de *Yo soy tu padre* lo conocemos incluso los que no hemos visto las películas :)

Comentarios:

- Me suena haber oído hablar del *Lado Oscuro* para *Dark Side*.
- uso [*papá*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rl3l8xg) para traducir *father* (*1. m. coloq. padre (‖ varón que ha engendrado o ejerce de padre)*).
- uso [*harto*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K2bf18r) para traducir "enough" (*3. adj. indef. cult. Mucho o abundante*).
- uso [*sentir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XbVfLnt) en su segunda entrada para traducir *feelings* (*1. m. Sentimiento del ánimo*).
- uso [*ojear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QxZ58KD) para traducir *search* (*3. tr. Lanzar ojeadas a algo.*), si bien estoy pensando en usar [*aojar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=325q68I) pues parece encajar mejor con el significado de *buscar* que *ojear* proporciona solo levemente.

Evolución:

- De 165 a 162 cambiando *sabes que es verdad* por *lo sabes cierto*.

Comment: Tranquilo, contaba con el uso de "papá" en vez de "padre" para las traducciones. :-)

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>159</s> <s>157</s> 151 caracteres

> —Jamás me uniré a ti.
>   —Si conocieses el poder del Lado Oscuro. Obi-wan calló qué pasó con tu padre.
>   —Le bastó decir que le mataste.
>   —No. Soy tu padre.
>   —Falso. ¡Imposible!
>   —Reflexiona. Sabes que es cierto.

---

Comentarios:

Traduzco el diálogo `Obi-Wan no te dijo lo que le pasó a tu padre. Me dijo lo suficiente. Dijo que tú le mataste.` omitiendo al sujeto Obi-wan en el comentario de Luke.

Mantengo "padre" aunque pierda un par de letras. Elimino el "yo" de "yo soy tu padre". Ese "yo" tiene un claro énfasis en el mensaje durante la conversación, pero técnicamente no se necesita gracias a la conjugación del verbo.

Update:

Cambio `Suficiente con decir que le mataste` por `Le bastó decir que le mataste`, que me ahorro 6 letras.

Comment: Una traducción genial, y encima respetando "padre". Mis felicitaciones.

Comment: Qué bien visto lo de _Falso. ¡Imposible!_, mantiene todo el sentido y es incluso más cinematográfico.